# Why initialize unique_ptr with a make_unique call?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, gotw

**Taken from: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/**

Why should we write:

```
auto pb = unique_ptr<base>{ make_unique<derived>() };
```

Instead of just:

```
auto pb = make_unique<derived>();
```

My only guess is that if we want `auto`, we need to help it deduce the right type (`base` here).

If so, then for me this would be really doubtful merit.. to type `auto` and then type a lot of initialization on the right side of `=` ..

What am I missing?

Comment: Erm, Why? Because you want the first thing and not the second? They are not equivalent. (Check `decltype(pb)`)

Comment: one thing is clear here, if you have a smart_pointer of derived you cannot easily cast it to base. because unlike base *x; and derived *y;
there is no relation in the type hierarchy.

Comment: Just wondering, would `unique_ptr<base> pb =  make_unique<derived>();` be simpler? Because `auto` exists doesn't mean we must use it.

Comment: @FredericS: It would be slightly shorter, more familiar to people not used to C++11, and less explicit since it involves an implicit conversion. Whether that makes it "simpler" or not is an aesthetic judgement.

Comment: I still like `auto pb = unique_ptr<base>(new derived());` for clarity.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker even better with uniform-init: `{}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the point is that the first option makes `pb` a `unique_ptr<base>`, while the second option makes `pb` a `unique_ptr<derived>`. Whether both are correct or not in your situation depends on what you have to do with `pb` - but definitely the two are not equivalent.

If the relevant part of your program needs to work with a `unique_ptr<base>` (perhaps because later on you are going to let it to point to an instance of a *different* derived class), then the second solution is simply not viable.

For example:

```
auto pb = unique_ptr<base>{ make_unique<derived>() };
// ...
pb = make_unique<derived2>(); // This is OK
// ...
```

Whereas:

```
auto pb = make_unique<derived>();
// ...
pb = make_unique<derived2>(); // ERROR! "derived2" does not derive from "derived"
// ...
```

Comment: @AndyProwl hiding evidence, are we?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Me? I would never do that! (...how much for deleting your comment?) ;)

Comment: C++ is so ugly now. I want my `new`/`delete` back!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition No one has taken them away. You simply have alternatives now.

Answer (score 6):

> My only guess is that if we want auto, we need to help it deduce the right type (base here).

That's exactly right. Without the conversion, `pb` would be a pointer to `derived` which might not be what you want. For example, you couldn't reassign it to own a `base` or other derived-class object.

> If so, then for me this would be really doubtful merit..

I'm inclined to agree. The author notes in a [comment](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/#comment-10332) that he did it because he likes to use type deduction as much as possible, with explicit conversions where necessary. Time will tell whether that style becomes commonplace.

Comment: +1 for the link to Herb's comment (and your nice answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
auto pb = unique_ptr<base>{ make_unique<derived>() };
```

the above creates a `unique_ptr<base>` that contains a `derived`.

```
auto pb = make_unique<derived>();
```

the above creates a `unique_ptr<derived>` that contains a `derived`.

While replacing the 2nd with the 1st could be acceptable, they actually do different things.

As an aside, searching for `make_unique` in the linked-to article results in someone answering this very question there.